# Magento 2 controller override is not working

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, controllers, dependency-injection

I am trying to override the "customer-edit-post" controller but am getting 500 Internal server error with following script.

`di.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost" type="VestricsM2\Connector\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

Contoller: `PackageName\ModuleName\Contoller\Index\Post.php`

```
<?php

  namespace VestricsM2\Connector\Controller\Index;

  class Post extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost{

     protected $logger;

     protected $resourceConfig;

     public function __construct(
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
                   ) {

       parent::__construct($context);
     }

    public function execute(){
       echo "Testtttt"; exit;
     }
   }
```

Comment: And now I'm trying to think what our best practice is for overriding a controller action. You have three options.

Comment: Can you please follow @Kishan Patadia post exatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your **di.xml** as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost" type="VestricsM2\Connector\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

Also remove constructor from controller class.

Comment: not showing any error but it's not going to my custom controller. the customer details updating

Comment: @Ramesh Have you solved this problem, same issue is with me if you can help

Answer (score 2):

Your **constructor needs to match the original constructor** so in your case you can simply remove your `__construct` method here as it's useless.

Comment: not showing any error but it's not going to my custom controller.  the customer details updating

Answer (score 0):

This below script is working at di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost" type="\VestricsM2\Connector\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```